# Is font-display supported?

Tags: css

I'm trying to optimize the loading of fonts on a website. I found this website https://beamtic.com/optimizing-font-load giving suggestions to improve the fonts loading.
I read the section "Avoid font swapping" which suggests to use font-display: optional but Chrome does not seem to recognize it.
In the documentation of Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display) I understand that this descriptor is used in @font-face only.
So the first website is giving wrong advices? If I can use font-display: optional only in @font-face how it works?
If I use a custom font for example body {font-family: 'My font', Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;} and I declare

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'My font';
  ...
  font-display: optional;
```

the first font that will be loaded is Verdana?

I tried to declare font-display: optional in body but Chrome does not recognize it.

Comment: Chrome has full support of font display - see the browser compatibility part of the docs you link to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display#browser_compatibility

Comment: ok it supports in @font-face context only

Answer (score 0):

You can always use this site to check if a tag is supported or not, they are pretty up to date.
You can just type in the tag and see what browsers supports it

https://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome -60  Firefox - 58    IE - No Edge - 79   Safari - 11.1

this browser with version only supported to font-display

Answer (score 0):

The following desktop browsers support `font-display`.

[image]

Google has written an amazing articel about it.

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/font-display/

Use https://caniuse.com/?search=font-display for browser support.